# how to find and input text into a text box?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a dice bot for a site https://www.999doge.com/ I cant use selenium so I don't know what to. I already figured out how to go to the page using request I need help figuring out how I can login my finding and filling in a text box with my user/pass. here is my code

```
import requests

username = "gangstardog"

headers = {

   'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.17763'
}
with requests.Session() as s:
    url = "https://www.999doge.com/"
    r = s.get(url, headers=headers)
    print(r.content)
```

Comment: why can't you use selenium, it seems like it may be required to do this

Comment: You should probably look up the API docs for whatever this website does.

Comment: This website is dynamically generated, so u won't be able to scrape this site using only `requests` you will need to use something else like selenium or html-requests library to render that page https://requests.readthedocs.io/projects/requests-html/en/latest/
Just google how to log in using `requests` and u will see many threads about that, you will create a session, send post request with the params, and you're logged in

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here:

1. Use selenium to literally fill in the text box on a web page and submit it
2. Determine the URL when the form submits data and what data is submitted and use requests to do the same thing.